# how can I rotate square in Shiny app R programming?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I am a beginner in R, I want to rotate my drawn square.
Is there a function to rotate my drown shape

I want the drawn square to be rotated 45 degree

```
  rect(
            xright = 10,
            ytop = 10,
            xleft = 0,
            ybottom = 0,
            density = 40,
            col = "lightblue",
            border = "lightblue"
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a way to do this with the `rect()` function directly, but you could make another function that does the rotation of the coordinates at the corners:

```r
rect_rot <- function(
  xright = 10,
  ytop = 10,
  xleft = 0,
  ybottom = 0,
  density = 40,
  rot = 0, 
  centerx = xleft + (xright-xleft)/2, 
  centery = ybottom + (ytop - ybottom)/2, 
  ...){
  x <- c(xright, xright, xleft, xleft, xright) - (xright-xleft)/2 
  y <- c(ytop, ybottom, ybottom, ytop, ytop) - (ytop-ybottom)/2 
  coords <- cbind(x,y)
  rads <- (-rot)*pi/180
  R <- matrix(c(cos(rads), sin(rads), -sin(rads), cos(rads)), ncol=2)
  newcoords =  t(R %*% t(coords))
  newx <- newcoords[,1] + centerx
  newy <- newcoords[,2] + centery
  polygon(newx, newy, ...)
}
```

The `rot` parameter is in degrees clockwise and in the function is converted into radians to be amenable to the trigonometric functions in R.  The ellipses (`...`) are other parameters that can be passed down to the `polygons()` function that draws the rectangle.  The rotation rotates around the origin (0,0), so initially the coordinates are centered on the origin and then by default moved back to have the same center as the original polygon, though this can be changed through the `centerx` and `centery` parameters. Here are a few examples.

```
plot(c(-30, 30), c(-50, 50), type="n")
rect_rot()
rect_rot(rot=45, border="red")
rect_rot(rot=45, border="blue", centerx=20, centery=-10)
```

[image]

---

### EDIT

In answer to the question about drawing a rhombus, you could do it this way:

```r
rhombus <- function(xleft, xright, ybottom, ytop, ...){
  x <- c(xleft, xleft + (xright-xleft)/2, xright, xleft + (xright-xleft)/2, xleft)
  y <- c(ybottom + (ytop-ybottom)/2, ytop, ybottom + (ytop-ybottom)/2, ybottom, ybottom + (ytop-ybottom)/2)
  polygon(x, y, ...)
}
plot(c(-30, 30), c(-50, 50), type="n")
rhombus(0, 10, 0, 10, border="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to draw rhombus??

Comment: @AbdooShawky I edited the answer to propose a solution to drawing a rhombus.